# Sealing - Do sheathing and bottom plate have to be sealed (caulked) in CA?

Tags: framing, flashing, sheathing, sill, house-wrap

**Context:** I am about to place the house wrap on the sheathing of my house addition in California. I am looking at flashing my doors and windows properly to make the house water tight. I am looking for advice on whether the sheathing should be sealed with caulking to the bottom sill plate and to the foundation. The sill has a gasket between the concrete slab on grade and sill.

**Question:** Does the bottom of the sheathing need to be caulked or sealed to the bottom sill plate and to the foundation to prevent any air or humidity to get under the sill or inside the walls/house?

Comment: Have heard about sealing of the vapour barrier on the inside, but think having some air movement on the outside is good  for the walls.  Allows any moisture that might get in a way to escape/leave.

Comment: @crip659 -- you want the air/vapor barrier plane on the outside in any climate where air conditioning is a thing

Comment: Have you considered a suitable tape for the application?

Comment: Yes, I have a flashing tape I could use. But I am would like to get an understanding on whether or not it is required.